# I'm unable to launch my android emulator using TITANIUM STUDIO

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

i've been trying to get my android emulator to work in my mac using titanium studio.

here is log sheet i'm getting when ever i'm trying to run:

```
**[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[INFO] logfile = /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/Titanium WorkSpace/abc/build.log
[DEBUG] /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/builder.py simulator abc /Applications/Android SDK/sdk /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/Titanium WorkSpace/abc com.xxx.abc 1 QVGA 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 2340, in <module>
    builder = Builder(project_name,sdk_dir,project_dir,template_dir,app_id)
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/builder.py", line 341, in __init__
self.sdk = AndroidSDK(sdk, self.tool_api_level)
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/androidsdk.py", line 49, in __init__
self.set_api_level(api_level)
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/androidsdk.py", line 53, in set_api_level
self.find_platform_dir()
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/3.0.2.GA/android/androidsdk.py", line 131, in find_platform_dir
raise Exception("No \"%s\" or \"%s\" in the Android SDK" % ('android-%s' % api_level, android_api_levels[api_level]))
Exception: No "android-8" or "android-2.2" in the Android SDK**
```

Hope you guys help me out. i have no idea whats going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception: No "android-8" or "android-2.2" in the Android SDK**

usually means that there is no Virtual Device for the selected Android version. Either you are missing some SDK's (Notice: If you want to run Android 2.2 you need to download the SDK resources for 2.2 with SDK Manager) or Titanium Studio is doing something wrong (what i already noticed on a mac machine).

So...

1. Ensure that you've downloaded SDK resources for 2.2 (SDK Manager should be available via Titanium Studion). Restart Titanium Studio.
2. If (1) is true and this doesn't help:

   1. Check environment variables (JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_SDK). Restart Titanium Studio.
   2. Only if this also does not help: Create your own Virtual Device with AVD Manager and call it android-8 or android-2.2 OR run the emulator first and then click run in Titanium Studio.

**But** the usual way is clicking Run in Titanium Studio which starts the emulator and runs your app. So please also have a look at [Setting up Titanium Studio](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Setting_up_Titanium_Studio), [Installation Troubleshooting](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installation_Troubleshooting), [Environment Variables](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables) and of course [the compatibility matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix) which contains required versions.

Answer (score 0):

really old question...but I came across it and found a solution by installing the older version of Android SDK. Titanium would not work with 3.x or 4.x, but all the sample apps (and now my production app) worked with the 2.2 package.